# multirange union statement doesn't work

Tags: vba, range

```
Private Sub workbook_open()

Select the range of cells

Dim r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, multirange

Set r1 = Sheets("SE_SQ").Range("Ad1:ak50")

Set r2 = Sheets("Main").Range("Ad1:ak50")

Set r3 = Sheets("Feeler").Range("Ad1:ak50")

Set r4 = Sheets("Egg Crates").Range("Ad1:ak50")

Set r5 = Sheets("other").Range("Ad1:ak50")

Set multirange = Union(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5)
```

This last set range gives me a run-time error 1004. What is wrong with this statement?

Comment: This question would be better if it were _edited_ to include details about which programming language/environment this is being used in. I _think_ this is an Excel question, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Excel's `Union()` does not work for ranges across different sheets. Either copy all ranges into one sheet or consider using a different VBA container such as collection, array, or dictionary. Below passes range values through all such containers and iterately prints values in each:

```
Public Sub RangeTest()
    Dim r1, r2, r3, r4, r5
    Dim d1 As New Collection, d2(1 To 250) As Variant, d3 As Object
    Dim i As Variant, n As Variant, num As Integer

    Set r1 = Sheets("SE_SQ").Range("Ad1:ak50")
    Set r2 = Sheets("Main").Range("Ad1:ak50")
    Set r3 = Sheets("Feeler").Range("Ad1:ak50")
    Set r4 = Sheets("Egg Crates").Range("Ad1:ak50")
    Set r5 = Sheets("other").Range("Ad1:ak50")

    ' COLLECTION '
    For Each i In Array(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5)
        For Each n In i
            d1.Add n
        Next n
    Next i        
    For Each i In d1: Debug.Print i: Next i

    ' ARRAY '
    num = 1
    For Each i In Array(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5)
        For Each n In i
            d2(num) = n
            num = num + 1
        Next n
    Next i        
    For Each i In d2: Debug.Print i: Next i

    ' DICTIONARY '
    Dim key As Variant, val As Variant
    Set d3 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    num = 1
    For Each i In Array(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5)
        For Each n In i
            key = num: val = n: d3.Add key, val
            num = num + 1
        Next n
    Next i        
    For Each i In d3: Debug.Print d3(i): Next i

End Sub
```